# How to run a shell function as a command in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a function in shell script and i want to use it in my ansible playbook

my shell script -

```
wait_for_apt_locks () {
    while sudo fuser /var/{lib/cache/apt/archives}/{lock,lock-frontend} >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        echo "Waiting for apt locks"
        sleep 1
    done
```

i want to use this function wait_for_apt_locks in my playbook wait.yml

is the below the right way to use it?

```
- name: source /tmp/function.sh
      shell: |
        source /tmp/functions.sh
        wait_for_apt_locks
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any suggestions regarding loading bash functions - if your example works, then it works!

But do note that Ansible has a [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module used for monitoring ports or files.

Perhaps this is a more Ansible-native solution for dealing with lock files.

From https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html#examples:

```
- name: Wait until the lock file is removed
  wait_for:
    path: /var/lock/file.lock
    state: absent
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the shell script for the sole purpose of calling it here, you can skip the script file and simply execute the logic inline. At the end of the day, if it works it works.

```yaml
- name: Run a shell command inline
  become: true
  command: >
    while fuser {lib/cache/apt/archives}/{lock,lock-frontend} >/dev/null 2>&1; do
      echo "Waiting for apt locks";
      sleep 1;
    done
  ignore_errors: no
  args:
    chdir: /var
```

[Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module)